# A Problem in understanding of some fundamentals in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm a beginner in python and I have a problem with some basics of it.

```
m  = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = []

for col in range(3):
    b.append(sum(i[col] for i in m))

print(b)
```

This code will sum the columns of m.

But if I extract the `for i in m` and write it as follows:

```
for col in range(3):
    for i in m:
        b.append(sum(i[col]))

print(b)
```

it doesn't work and gives me an error. All I've done is extracting the loop from the parenthesis.

What is the problem and what should I do?

Comment: What do you think `sum(i[col])` means?  And what error are you getting?

Comment: `sum(i[col] for i in m)`: parentheses for `sum` around the whole for "loop" (comprehension). `sum(i[col])`: parentheses for `sum` around a single item (`i[col]`). So these are *not* the same.

Comment: You're summing only one item. Isn't that unusual?

Comment: Your two codes aren’t the same, so it shouldn’t be surprising that the results are different; why are you surprised?

Comment: You need to learn to debug these things yourself. Did you *check* what `i[col]` is? Did you try to just do something like `sum(3)`?

Comment: PyCharm is free, install it and set breakpoints in your code to see what's happening!

Comment: Note that ideally, a question title will let someone know _exactly what your problem is_, so they can tell if their problem is the same, and thus if they can learn from your answers. Our goal is not just to be somewhere people can go to have their questions asnwered after they ask them, but to be somewhere people can _find preexisting answers, because someone else asked the same thing in the past_. For that to work, though, we need questions to be posed in a way that makes them searchable, and well-summarized with a meaningful title.

Answer (score 0):

Note the original code has a single call to append each time around the outer for loop.

Try:

```
m  = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = []

for col in range(3):
    toadd = 0
    for i in m:
        toadd += sum(i[col])
    b.append(toadd)

print(b)
```

Comment: Thanks warmly, Barny.
It still has an error in toadd += sum(i[col]).

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, use some print statements to see whats going on within the for loops:

```
m  = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = []

for col in range(3):
    print([i[col] for i in m])

print("----")

for col in range(3):
    print("new col")
    for i in m:
        print(i[col])
```

outputs:

```
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
----
new col
1
4
7
new col
2
5
8
new col
3
6
9
```

So the first for loop, `i[col]` is returning a list of numbers and in the second for loop, `i[col]` is returning an `int`.

This may give you a clue why `sum(i[col])` is returning an error in the second for loop.

Comment: Thanks warmly, Tom. I did use print to see what happens but spyder editor showed some non-relevant response:
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000230201A5580>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000230201A5580>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000230201A5580>

Comment: Sorry, error in my code there, I have updated it so it should now be correct

Comment: No worries, the best way to learn to code is by debugging, you get a better understanding of what is happening! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in range(3):  # col is an int
    for i in m:  # each i is a list e.g. [1, 2, 3]
        b.append(sum(i[col]))  # i[col] is an int, e.g. i[0] = 1 or i[1] = 2
```

The problem is that `sum()` receives `iterable` as argument not an `int` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum